# Does building a node require syncing the block and context data from scratch?

Tags: node

When building a node, do I have to sync its block data from scratch or can a load some kind of snapshot and finish syncing from there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's possible to start with `tezos-node` data from another node and finish the sync from there. I do this by running the new `tezos-node` briefly to have it create `~/.tezos-node` and the usual files in that. Then I stop `tezos-node` and do the following:

```
cd ~/.tezos-node
rm -r context store
curl http://quicksync.tzdutch.com/latest.tar.lz4 | lz4 -d | tar xf -
```

The download and expand step can take several hours. Then I restart `tezos-node` and let it finish syncing the data.

See https://www.tzdutch.com/quicksync/ about the source of the context and store data.

Comment: How hard would it be to create a proof that such a tarball matches all blocks for some height, and the put them on ipfs on some regular basis?  I have been downloading the tzdutch tarball e few times too, and it's great! But seems we should/could have a more general solution for this?